# Observer for removing firebase user when app is terminated

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, observers, notificationcenter

i'm trying to use an observer that checks if the app is closed in a particular viewController and then remove the firebase User. This should work but the user is not deleted. Any idea why ? There is a user, i'm sure of this, and using terminateApp() in viewDidLoad removes the user, only not when used together with UIApplicationWillTerminate notification.

my code

```
var currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser

override func viewDidLoad() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(terminateApp), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillTerminate, object: nil)
}

@objc func terminateApp() {
    if let user = currentUser {
        user.delete { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("There was an error deleting the user: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: A bit more explanation for my situation:

In the "Register your account VC" i use Firebase auth to register an account with username and password. The check happens here. If the mail address exists or the address is badly formatted, i display an alert with standard firebase error description. If the address does not exist, i create the profile, then go to the second VC.

In the "Complete your profile VC" there is no possibility to go back, i only want the user to complete the profile. The profile is saved in a users collection in the firestore DB. When typing the usersname, the db is queried for existing usernames and result is displayed on screen immediately. If the user exists i get an x and the complete signup button is disabled. If the user does not exist a checkmark is displayed and the button becomes active. If signup is pressed, the users document will be created in the users collection and in addition, the username is added to the users Auth (user.uid)

What i want to do now is delete the user when the user doesn't complete the signup process. So terminates the app in the "Complete your profile" VC.

[image]

Comment: What user are you trying to delete? Do you want to delete the user from Firebase? And under what circumstances do you want the user deleted - when the app terminates normally only or when it crashes or when the user closes the app? Furthermore if this is a Firebase user is it an Authenticated user? Anonymous? Something else? All of that will determine how to handle this.

Comment: In the previous vc i create an authenticated user with e-mail address and password. Then i segue to this vc to complete the profile. I want the registered user to be deleted when the profile is not completed. So when the user quits the app from this vc !

Comment: How about not creating the user until their profile is complete? i.e. why go through creating a user if it may just be deleted? If you want to do it anyway the user needs to be obtained through Auth like this *let user = Auth.auth().currentUser* then *user?.delete { * will delete the user.

Comment: I don’t want to create the user in the second view. It had to be created in the first. So i want to do it anyway :) and that is the problem. The user exists. My currenUser = Auth.auth().currentUser. Only it won’t delete the when used in the observer. Maybe because it’s async ? Any code before user?.delete and after user?.delete gets executed. And if i use my function outside the observer it works too.

Comment: There's a few issues with this - for example. If the app crashes or the unit powers down between the first and second view, there would be no way for the user to go back and finish.

Comment: alright, i see. That's what i also wanted to know. If the app crashes or gets closed, if it's possible then for a function to be called to remove that user. But that doesn't cover a dead battery i guess. I'll try implementing it another way.